# Cancel website without taking it down

Tags: google-search

I have a website www.old.com. I want to remove it from all search engines. I only want to keep it as a reference for personal use. I developed a www.new.com with contents from old.com.

Can I just use robots.txt to inform search engines that old.com is no longer online?

I do not have 1 on 1 mapping of the URLs between these 2 sites. I just want get rid of old.com and use new.com. The old.com is used as a personal reference site.

Answer (score 1):

Setup your old site to 301 (permanent) redirect all urls to the equivalent urls on your new site. This will keep your SEO and will let search engines, like Google, know you've moved. It may take a while (weeks or months) for the change to become visible in the search engines as the search engine will need to scan your site to see the changes.